# nifi putFile process not writing to directory

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to write FlowFiles from a `ConsumerAMQP` process to files and attempted to use a `PutFile` process. But the files do not end up in the directory. I am new to NiFi so not sure how to debug this but did get an idea online to use a `Funnel` and see where the FlowFiles end up. They do end up in the `success` process so it indicates to me that the files make it to the process but not being submitted to the output directory. I also do not know how to specify the filenames or file extension and how to write a specific number of flowfiles to a file at a time.

The settings below:

[image]

These are the processes in the flow:

[image]

Could someone please advise?

this shows the actual putFile read/write count but no out count and no errors:

[image]

Comment: What is the error shown on PutFile when it is trying to write the files?

Comment: There is no error on the process; EDIT shows read/write with count but out= 0

Comment: Out showing 0 is correct because no flow files were transferred out of the processor since you auto-terminated success and have failure self-looped. If there are no errors on the processor and nothing in the failure loop, i think they are successfully being written but maybe going somewhere you are not expecting due to something with the windows file paths.